ad crawler errors,which can result in lost revenue
**Issue Details:
**
Ad Crawler Error: Restricted ad serving due to Crawler: Unknown error.
Affected URL: /wp-admin/customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2Fthemes.php
Impact Period: Last 7 days
Current Status:
Ad Requests: 66 restricted ad requests in the last 7 days.
Regular Ad Serving: 99% (6.53K ad requests).
Revenue Impact: My CPC has drastically decreased, with the CPC currently at $0.00 despite receiving 9 clicks today and having a CTR (Click Through Rate) of 9.00%. My earnings for today so far stand at a mere $0.01, with a total of $0.08 for the month.
enter image description here
